# How can we prove that $f(x) = \lfloor 1.5x \rfloor$ is not onto?

Tags: convergence-divergence

How can we prove that $f:\mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z, f(x) = \lfloor 1.5x \rfloor$ is not onto? While it's very obvious to see, how can I actually prove that this is in fact the case? Traditional methods that I would use don't seem applicable because of the floor part of the equation...

Comment: Where does the function go from and to?

Comment: Is your codomain (the set you map to) also the integers?

Comment: Yes, my bad for not specifying

Comment: The traditional method of simply looking at values to find one you can guess isn't in the codomain seems applicable....

Comment: Try graphing the function or thinking through examples methodically. Then try to write a proof that some particular value is not achieved.

Comment: Note that it's a good practice on Stack Exchange to include the statement of the question in the body of the question. It makes it easier for the reader, so they don't have to dart back and forth from the body to the title.

Answer (score 10):

Notice that $\lfloor 1.5x \rfloor $ is non-decreasing.

$f(1)=1$, $f(2)=3$.

We do not have a preimage for $2$.

Answer (score 2):

For all $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, $f(x) = \lfloor 1.5 x \rfloor$ is either equal to $1.5x$ or equal to $1.5x - 0.5$. So $2f(x) = 3x \text{ or } 3x - 1$. In particular:
\begin{align*}
2f(x) \equiv 0 \text{ or } 2 \pmod{3} \\
\implies f(x) \equiv 0 \text{ or } 1 \pmod{3}.
\end{align*}

Thus $f$ does not attain any value $\equiv 2 \pmod{3}$, so it cannot be onto.

Comment: @N.S. Thanks. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

You actually haven't defined the function completely. A proper definition needs to show the domain and codomain of the function i.e. $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ or $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb N$ etc. In general $f:A\rightarrow B$.

I'm assuming that you mean $f:\mathbb Z\rightarrow \mathbb Z$.

To prove the function isn't onto, just find one element $y \in B$ s.t. there is no element in $A$ that maps to $y$. Trying a few values, $f(0) = 0,\ f(1) = 1,\ f(2) = 3$. Seems we missed $2$. Can you prove that no future value will ever map to 2?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Find an element in the codomain that is not in the image (use your intuition here). Suppose it is $c\in\Bbb Z$. Then find the possible solutions for $\lfloor 1.5x\rfloor=c$. If the possible values for $x$ contain no integers, then there is no $x\in\Bbb Z$ such that $\lfloor 1.5x\rfloor=c$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your function is $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

$f$ isn't onto. Just choose any value $x \notin \mathbb{Z}$ and there won't be any correspondence in the domain of $f$.

Suppose by contradiction that given $y \notin \mathbb{Z}$ there is $x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ }st. f(x)=y$. Then $\lfloor{1.5x} \rfloor \notin \mathbb{Z}$, which is absurd by definition of floor function.

edit:

OP updated that it is $f:\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$.
Then, firstly note that $f$ is non-decreasing. Then take a look at the image set $Im (f) = \{ ..., -3, -2, 0, 1, 3, ... \}$ and you can see that there are integers in between those elements that aren't in the image set. Just take one of them, say $2$. Suppose there is $x$ in the domain of $f$ such that $f(x)=2$. Then $\lfloor 1.5x \rfloor = 2$, which means $ 2 \leq 1.5x < 3$ which is absurd since $x$ is an integer.

Comment: He has specified $f:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$.

Comment: OP clarified domain and codomain as $\mathbb Z \rightarrow \mathbb Z$.